# Try 'open()', except IOError in Python for loop

Tags: xml, python-2.7, for-loop, try-catch, except

(Python 2.7)
The code below searches directories for .xml files and searches for a string within each XML. I am trying to get an exception for when .xml files cannot be found (or opened).

So far when no XML is found, the 'with' statement is correctly not executed but it is ignoring 'except IOError' and proceeding past it.

```
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/DIRECTORY PATH HERE'):
    for file1 in files:
        if file1.endswith(".xml") and not file1.startswith("."):
            filePath = os.path.join(root, file1)

            try:
                with open(filePath) as f:
                    content = f.readlines()
                for a in content:
                    if "string" in a:
                        stringOutput = a.strip()
                        print 'i\'m here' + stringOutput

            except IOError:
                print 'No xmls found'
```

Comment: Do you get `IOError` exception in your program, even when `except IOError` is ignored ?

Comment: No, I cannot find a way of getting to 'except IOError'

Comment: It might be that file *do* exists, but the content  is empty, so `for` loop won't be executed. The reason is that you are filtering XML files, so this scenario will be probable. You can check if content is empty and print the file name to test it out.

Comment: Testing this on empty folders I receive no output, so neither 'im here' nor 'no xmls found' are printed

Comment: That is correct, because, you shouldn't get any output since `os.walk` can't find any files. What do you want to do exactly ? Do you want to be notified when either no files or no xml files are found ?

Comment: Yes I want to reach the 'except' so I can run the print 'no xmls found' . Should my 'try' / 'except' be earlier? I can't see where it could be :(

Comment: `IOError` (or `OSError`) will be raised only if opening file was attempted and failed. And you have told your code to do **nothing** when file does not end with 'xml' extension (so it definitely does not trying to open anything). What about _counting_ *.xml files and printing a message when that count is 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments, I think this is what you are looking for.

```
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/PATH"):
    if not files:
        print 'path ' + root + " has no files"
        continue

    for file1 in files:
        if file1.endswith(".xml") and not file1.startswith("."):
            filePath = os.path.join(root, file1)

            with open(filePath) as f:
                content = f.readlines()

                for a in content:
                    if "string" in a:
                        stringOutput = a.strip()
                        print 'i\'m here' + stringOutput
        else:
            print 'No xmls found, but other files do exists !'
```